# Three.js camera rotation error

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

Firebug is throwing an error saying that "THREE is not defined" on my var camera and I honestly cannot see why. The error doesn't make any sense to me because as I see it; there is a defined THREE right that on the right hand of the equals sign.

```
        init();
        animate();

        function init()
        {
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 500;

            var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
            controls.addEventListener('change', render);

            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add(mesh);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        }

        function animate()
        {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();
        }

        function render()
        {
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
```

Comment: Have you included the three js script to ensure THREE is defined? `<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have; it is in the <body> of my html; just above what I shown here.

Comment: Well I guess it *should* work then... Double check that you have no network errors downloading the three js source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good except you're defining your variable inside the init() function which means those variables are local to the init() function and will not be recognized outside of it.

Declare your variables outside the function and that should help solve the problem. As an example:

```
var camera, controls, scene, geometry, material, mesh, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 500;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you are not including three.js script correctly. Check Firebug and watch for THREE variable  - it must be defined before you start working with THREE.JS. Check for network errors if it was loaded properly.

Next, ensure to run your code after rest of the page is loaded.

```
window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

This will call init function only after page is loaded

Then, define your variables in global scope and not inside init function. And also, don't forget to call render function inside your animate function.